# In-memory datastore in Haskell

Tags: data-structures, haskell

I want to implement an in-memory datastore for a web service in Haskell. I want to run transactions in the `STM` monad.

When I google *hash table steam Haskell* I only get this: `Data. BTree. HashTable. STM.` The module name and complexities suggest that this is implemented as a tree. I would think that an array should be more efficient for mutable hash tables.

Is there a reason to avoid using an array for an `STM` hashtable?
Do I gain anything with this steam hash table or should I just use a steam ref to an `IntMap`?

Comment: Note, if you use `TVar IntMap

Comment: @jozefg what do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, apparently I lost the rest of that, I was going to say you'll get crappy parallelism because modifing `Store ! blah` and `Store ! baz` will have to be sequential

Comment: When you say "an in-memory datastore", do you mean something like [acid-state](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state)?

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame I am looking for something really more simple than that. Actually I am looking for a simple mutable map that runs in the stm monad. I know I have several options for this, and I am trying to evaluate which one is better.

Comment: STM is especially bad, if you have a lot of writes to your table, but you can solve it partially by wrapping the values in tvars too. Now only inserts are costly, updates can be done parallel. Something like this:

`import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as S

newtype STMMap k v = STMMap { unSTMMap :: TVar (S.HashMap k (TVar v) ) }`

But it really depends on the context. In some applications IORefs where performing better with atomicModifyIORef to write to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a hash table implementation based directly on an array is that some of operations on it will inevitably require linear time array resizing (i.e., creating a bigger/smaller array and copying all data to it). There are multiple standard algorithms that approach this problem, like [Linear Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing) or [Cuckoo Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).

Not so long ago another algorithm named [Hash Array Mapped Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) emerged, which gained a great popularity across functional languages like Clojure, Scala and, of course, Haskell (with the "unordered-containers" and "hamtmap" libraries) due to support of persistent data structures.

Not long ago I released [an STM-specialized containers library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-containers) based on that algorithm named "stm-containers", which should fit your task perfectly. You can also check out [an introductory blog post](http://nikita-volkov.github.io/stm-containers/), covering a motivation behind the library and providing benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I haven't tested your package but it looks interesting. I will check it later, but based on your post I am ready to believe that it fits my initial goal.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation you reference is part of a package for implementing a concurrent B-Tree. The HashTable itself is implemented as an array of TVars of Data.Map objects.

The quoted complexity values are *worst-case*. Remember that hashtables are usually O(N) worst case for lookup, insertion, and deletion. Using Map for the buckets brings it down to O(log(N)).